# WCF transport security, changing the certificates dynamically

Tags: c#, wcf, security, service, transport

I am using WCF services with C#.
I am using the transport security mode by setting the client and service certificates.

In the middle of operation I would like to change the certificates that I am using and use certificates signed by other CA.

Is it possible to change these certificates in the middle of operation without restarting the service host? If so how?

Is it enough if I just call set certificate with other certificate passed:

```
serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(...)
serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(...)
```

Someone have encountered this problem and resolved it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  In any event, changing either or both would most likely fault the channel, requiring the connection to be reestablished.  That's assuming you could even change them - which I doubt, as most things are set before the host or client are opened and cannot be changed.

Comment: You can't change certificates without restarting the web service, unfortunately. I've looked into this extensively. There's no way to do it. Sorry

Comment: @Brian: My apologies. I didn't see your comment before posting my answer. Post your comment as an answer so OP can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this as a high-availability issue. You can't do it. The service acquires its certificate when the ServiceHost opens and never again.

If your goal is to support HA, you need to put multiple services behind a load-balancer and restart them one-by-one.

Comment: OP: Please don't mark this as accepted until @Brian has a chance to answer (he answered it before me, in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change certificates without restarting the web service, unfortunately. I've looked into this extensively. There's no way to do it. Sorry